# Failed to install Nano editor on Mac

Tags: macos, nano

I downloaded the latest version of nano and I followed the instructions described on its website, but I was stopped by step 3:

1. Download the source file (nano-2.2.6.tar.gz) and unpack it.
2. Open Terminal and navigate to the directory (nano-2.2.6) and type
3. ./configure
4. make
5. make install

The error messages are as follows:

> Chriss-MacBook-Air:nano-2.2.6 Chris$ ./configure
>   checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin11.4.0
>   checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin11.4.0
>   checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin11.4.0
>   checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
>   checking whether build environment is sane... yes
>   checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
>   checking for gawk... no
>   checking for mawk... no
>   checking for nawk... no
>   checking for awk... awk
>   checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
>   checking for style of include used by make... none
>   checking for gcc... no
>   checking for cc... no
>   checking for cl.exe... no
>   configure: error: in `/Users/Chris/Downloads/nano-2.2.6':
>
>   configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
>
>   See`config.log' for more details.
>   Chriss-MacBook-Air:nano-2.2.6 Chris$

Comment: Do you have GCC installed( Xcode should do) On you mac?

Comment: no i haven't installed yet

Comment: If you have a Lion, You can download for free from the Appstore :http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12

Answer (score 3):

You need to install GCC on you mac. It's not installed by default -- you need to add the development tools.

Installing [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) will solve your problem.

Comment: You can find Xcode in the Additional Programs folder on one of the disks that came with your system.

Comment: Oops.. It seems nothing change after I finish installing Xcode. Do I need to do some changes to the PATH?

Comment: Recent versions of Xcode have the command line tools as an optional install.

Comment: @FallenSatan: You dont need to manually set the PATH, Xcode should take care of it. Can you try restarting your machine?

Comment: @Downvoter: What's the down vote for?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  The problem is that on current versions of XCode the command line tools are not installed by default, you have to go to preferences -> downloads and tell xcode to instal the command line tools.